# Akka.Net Remoting: ActorSelection vs. IActorRef

Tags: c#, akka, akka.net

Using Akka.net with remoting.  [This article](https://petabridge.com/blog/when-should-I-use-actor-selection/) has the following to say about using ActorSelection:

> The other time when I tend to use an ActorSelection is when I am
>   initially communicating with a remote actor system.

What I don't quite understand is how to convert that initial ActorSelection into an IActorRef that I can continue to use.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The simplest way here is to use `actorSelection.ResolveOne(timeout)` method, which will return `Task<IActorRef>`. Task may also end with timeout or `ActorNotFoundException` in case when no actor was found under provided path.

Another - more actor-idiomatic - way is to send `Identify(correlationId)` message to actor selection. It should respond with `ActorIdentity(correlationId, actorRef)` reply. Be aware that it may not respond at all, if there was no one to listen under provided actor selection.

Comment: So which way is should I prefer in which case?

Comment: Rule of thumb is that inside actors we prefer to use messages over tasks. So when you're resolving `IActorRef` from actor selection inside an actor, use `Identify` and set receiver for `ActorIdentity`. When resolving from outside of actor system, use `ResolveOne`.